# NumberPicker change default style in API 14 and lower to API 19

Tags: android, numberpicker

Can I change default style of `NumberPicker` form the **right** one to the **left** one? Is it possible?

On the **right** is `API16`, **left** is `API 19`

[image]

Comment: What's the theme you're using ?

Comment: I didn't set any theme.

Comment: Are the styles still different if you set the app theme to Holo for example ?

Comment: I have set to holo but no luck. Still deference

Comment: I'm convinced this is a theme concern that can be fixed using theming. But i've look into API 16 and 19 without finding differences in their used layouts so far. They're device default themes and styles are the same regarding `NumberPicker` and the layout files, and the styles content are the same.

Comment: I've looked into NumberPicker source code, and see that there's customs attributes for theming coming from `com.internal.android.R.attr`, but no background or such. The best guest i can give is try modifying the solid color of the widget

Comment: so, you mean it's impossible to do right?

Comment: No, i really believe it's possible, but this involves digger deeper which i cannot make tonight ;) If there's no answer tomorrow morning i'll try do it

Comment: oh I see, thank you for your information anyway goodnight :)

Comment: I finally saw that the difference between API 16 and 19 is : in version 16 no matter what's your theme, the layout `number_picker` is inflated, whereas in API 19 it can be customized using attribute `internalLayout` and defaults to `number_picker_with_selector_wheel`.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve my own question by using this library.

[SimonVT/android-numberpicker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker)

> This is a backport of the Android 4.2 NumberPicker.

So, I can get 4.2 theme for lower API.

Setup is very simple, Please try a sample project in the library pack.